# MySQL select from database not null

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select information from database but I don't want to select `NULL`.

My query:

```
SELECT percent, cost, userid FROM games ORDER BY `percent` ASC LIMIT 5
```

and it's selecting `NULL` value, how to don't select `NULL`.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhXl7.png)

Comment: `where whateverfieldyouwant is not null`, then...

Comment: Alternatively, if you want the rows, but to not receive null values, this can be used `SELECT IFNULL(whateverfieldyouwant, someothervaluelike0) AS whateverfieldyouwant ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `WHERE` statement with the `IS NOT null` operator.

```
SELECT percent
    , cost
    , userid
FROM games
WHERE percent IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY percent ASC
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IS NOT NULL` can be used in the `WHERE` clause.

[Read the manuals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html) ;)

```
SELECT percent,cost,userid
FROM games
WHERE `YourAwesomeColumn` IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY `percent` ASC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` condition must be written after `WHERE`:
http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/order_by.php

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about that